# Clicking button on webpage that was added by a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am using a chrome extension that dynamically adds a new button to a webpage. The extension works fine, but requires a human to click the added button on the webpage to start. I am trying to create an extension that click the button automatically.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work. It interacts with the webpage around it, but not the added button.

*To be clear, I am not trying to click a button inside an extension popup. This extension adds a button to the pages HTML as the page loads.

```
$("#button-id").click()

document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0].click()

document.getElementById("button-id").click()
```

If I call

```
document.getElementById("button-id")
```

it returns:

```
<button class=​"button-class" tabindex=​"0" title=​"Button Title" id=​"button-id">​</button>​
```

so the console sees the button, but the click function is not triggering anything.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the native behavior of the target element you would like to achieve you can or cannot use it programmatically created events. In example if you would like to trigger a click - so simply create a mouse event and dispatch it on target node:

```
const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click');
const targetNode = document.getElementById('xxx');
targetNode.dispatch(clickEvent);
```

Some of the native behavior cannot be triggered with such manually created events. E.g. native select cannot be opened as the event dispatched on it should have `isTrusted` field set to true, while with manual creation it will be set to false with property descriptor `configurable` set to false as well.

Comment: I tried this with the actual button id and got this error: "autoclick.js:3 (anonymous function)" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of null"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your JS file is being called before the extensions file has run meaning the button has not yet been added to the DOM when your code runs.

If you're able to call your code after the other extension has been run that might be your solution. Otherwise try this hacky workaround..

```
var buttonTrigger = setInterval( function() {
    var buttonElement = document.getElementById( 'button-id' );
    if ( buttonElement ) {

        var eventType = 'click'; // click | mousedown | mouseup | mouseover ..
        var eventObject = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
            eventObject.initEvent( eventType, true, false );

        buttonElement.dispatchEvent( eventObject );

        clearInterval( buttonTrigger );
    }
}, 100 );
```

This will loop every 100ms until the button is found and will trigger the click event.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/zkyfv1wj/

Another possibility is the extension isn't listening to the click event but the `mousedown` or `mouseup` events. To trigger these just change the `eventType` variable.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I ran this code. When trying to click the button added by the extension it did not work, but when I put a button id of a pre-existing button it worked. I believe the trigger is a click, but for some reason it doesn't like that it has been added by an extension and is not native to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change **run_at** field to **document_end** in *manifest.json* like below.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "your.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

I hope this is helpful for you.